# LINQ Include is not working as expected .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I just upgraded the application from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1

Encounter this issue. I have following methods:

```
var firstResult = await _context.UserCompany.Include(x => x.User).ToListAsync();
```

and

```
var secondResult = await _context.UserCompany.Include(x => x.User)
                                             .Where(x=>x.IsExecutive).ToListAsync();
```

In the **firstResult**, the navigation property **User** is populated.
In the **secondResult**, the navigation property **User** is null.

Why is that?